# using-declaration for friend function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, using, friend

In C++11 it is possible to make a public member of a private base class accessible to the outside (public) with a `using` declaration. For example

```
class A {
private:
    int i = 2;
public:
    void f() { i = 3; }

    friend bool operator==(const A& l, const A& r) { return l.i == r.i; }
};

class B : private A {
public:
    using A::f;
};

int main() {
    B b, b2;
    b.f();
}
```

`b.f()` is possible because of the `using A::f` in the definition of `B`.

Is it possible write a similar declaration which would make the up-cast from `B&` to `A&` possible for the friend function `operator==(A&, A&)`, so that `b == b2` can be called in `main()`?

Comment: You want it to be possible to upcast `B` to `A` in general?  Then why use private inheritance?  Or you just want `operator==` to work?  Then why not just declare another `operator==`?

Comment: It should be noted that the friend function is not a member of the class, so the term "upcast" shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, only `B` can internally cast itself to `A`, and it otherwise is not possible because from a client's perspective `B` is not **an** `A` but rather **has an** `A`

Even if you replaced your `friend bool operator=` with a member function `equals`:

```
class A {
private:
    int i = 2;
public:
    void f()  { i = 3; }

    bool equals(const A& r){return i == r.i;}
};

class B : private A {
public:
    using A::f;
    using A::equals; 
};
```

While this compiles, you cannot ever call `b.equals(b2)` because no implicit conversion is ever possible from a type of `B` to a type of `A` from the caller's perspective (due to private inheritance) .

You'll need to provide your own `operator==` or change your inheritance to `public` or `protected`. Here's an example where `B` declares its own `friend bool operator==`

```
class B : private A {
public:
    using A::f;
    friend bool operator==(const B& l, const B& r)
    {
        return (static_cast<A>(l) == static_cast<A>(r)) && true; 
        // "true" is a stand-in for some other condition
    }
};
```

Read more at [isocpp](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/private-inheritance)

---

Edit: 
If you really want to play games, you will notice that I said no *implicit* conversion is ever possible, but some *explicit* conversions are. Because `B` does technically derive from `A` you can do pointer casting to make it work, but I don't recommend it:

```
class A {
private:
    int i = 2;
public:
    void f()  { i = 3; }

    bool equals(const A* r){return i == r->i;}
};

class B : private A {
public:
    using A::f;
    using A::equals;
};

int main() {
    B b, b2;
    b.f();
    (::A*)(&b)->equals((::A*)(&b2));  
}
```

Or you could use pointer casting's ugly cousin, reference casting, if you wish to keep the original `operator==` syntax

```
class A {
private:
    int i = 2;
public:
    void f()  { i = 3; }

    friend bool operator==(const A& l, const A& r) { return l.i == r.i; }
};

class B : private A {
public:
    using A::f;
};

int main() {
    B b, b2;
    b.f();
    ((::A&)(b)) == ((::A&)(b2));  
}
```

See §11.2 [class.access.base] for more